# One url rewrite rule for 6 scenarios

Tags: php, regex, apache, url-rewriting

I have a rewrite rule that works for my index page

```
RewriteRule ^index$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^index/$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^index/page/(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])$ index.php?recordstart=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^index/page/(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])/$ index.php?recordstart=$1 [L]
```

I have 6 pages with similar scenario.

eg.

```
RewriteRule ^graduate$ graduate.php [L]
RewriteRule ^graduate/$ graduate.php [L]
RewriteRule ^graduate/page/(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])$ graduate.php?recordstart=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^graduate/page/(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])/$ graduate.php?recordstart=$1 [L]
```

I am looking for a rewrite that can match the six exact scenarios, instead of repeating the four lines six times.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
RewriteRule ^(scenario1|scenario2|scenario3)$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(scenario1|scenario2|scenario3)/$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(scenario1|scenario2|scenario3)/page/(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])$ $1.php?recordstart=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(scenario1|scenario2|scenario3)/page/(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])/$ $1.php?recordstart=$2 [L]
```

Feels dirty, but if you want to exclude all other scenario's except the ones mentioned.

**EDIT**: I'll add it here too that you can remove 2 lines of rules by checking the `/` with an `?` after it, it will match with or without the trailing `/`. The solution would become:

```
   RewriteRule ^(scenario1|scenario2|scenario3)/?$ $1.php [L]
   RewriteRule ^(scenario1|scenario2|scenario3)/page/(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])/?$ $1.php?recordstart=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteRule ^(index|graduate)/?$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(index|graduate)/page/(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])/?$ $1.php?recordstart=$2 [L]
```

`|` (pipe) is used in regex to provide alternatives, actually it means "or". You can add as many values as you want separated with `|`s.

If you know what you're doing you could also use `^([a-zA-Z]+)/?$` as well, but that would mean your rule captures every value that only consists of English letters. You must handle errors then.

I've simplified your rules by adding `/?` in the end which means an optional closing slash.

Answer (score 2):

First, just to save some space, you can shorten the first four rules to two like this:

```
RewriteRule ^index(/|)$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^index/page/(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])(/|)$ index.php?recordstart=$1 [L]
```

Then you can modify these two lines as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^(page1|page2|page3|page4|page5|page6)(/|)$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(page1|page2|page3|page4|page5|page6)/page/(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])(/|)$ $1.php?recordstart=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work (untested)?

```
RewriteRule ^(index|graduate|...)$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(index|graduate|...)/$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(index|graduate|...)/page/(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])$ $1.php?recordstart=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(index|graduate|...)/page/(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])/$ $1.php?recordstart=$2 [L]
```

I think you can also reduce the rules to the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(index|graduate|...)/?$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(index|graduate|...)/page/(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])/?$ $1.php?recordstart=$2 [L]
```